# Matlab mex -setup' is unable to find the compiler/SDK installed on the computer

Tags: matlab, mex

I have Matlab 2011a 32 bit installed on a Windows7 64 bit computer. I am getting the following error when trying to set up the default compiler:

```
****??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.****
```

(Sorry I am new to this site and don't have enough reputation to post image!)

I tried to resolve this issue by downloading and installing  'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express' from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html).

But even after installation Mex -setup is failing and it is not locating the installed compiler.

Kindly help me resolving this issue.

Comment: The page you linked to says you must install both VS2010 Express and Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1. Did you install the latter too? I believe this requirement is because the 64-bit C++ compiler is not installed with the Express version by default, and is available through the SDK.

Comment: Yes. I have installed SDK 7.1 as well. Is there any method to check if the installation is successful?

Comment: Not sure, check the start menu, there might be an entry called *VS2010 x64 Command Prompt* (or something along those lines). Open that and run the `cl` command. That should give you the compiler version (16.xx for VS2010) and say whether it is x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit). Then try compiling a simple program to verify it works. If you're not successful with any of that, your best bet is probably to contact the MathWorks' customer support.

Comment: You have to first uninstall all version of the _VC++ Redistributable_ (32 and 64 bits), then install VS2010, then the SDK. Follow the instructions on this link : [How do I install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1?](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96611-how-do-i-install-microsoft-visual-c-2010-and-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1). Do everything in the order described, and the patch given in step 3 is important, do not forget it.

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you for your answer. I ran 'cl' command on the VS2015 command prompt and it says 'cl' is not a recognized command!.